# How to update existing contact with Events,Note ,ImAccount ,Organization name ,Prefix and suffix in android?

Tags: android

How to update existing contact with Events,Note ,ImAccount ,Organization name ,Prefix and suffix in android ?

Comment: Will you explain your problem in detail

Comment: i have to update my phone book contact from my application . so i needs to update my existing contact right..? so need help.